# SubmitForm and return html as view ? AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, forms, view, return

I have a form that I submit and the html that is returned I what to display as a view in my app with rout for example /#/formResult

I managed to solve my case using Service and Resolve.

.when('/categories/:category/questionnaire', {
        template: '',
        controller: 'QuestionnaireController',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
        resolve: {
            Forms: function(Form) {

```
            return Form.Post( $('#catForm').serialize()); 
        }
    }
})
```

angular.module('MyApp').controller('QuestionnaireController',['$scope', '$sce', 'Forms', function($scope, $sce, Forms) {

```
    $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(Forms.data);
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

on success, you need to move to your view:

```
.success(data) {
    var dest = data.destination; // put here your correct var
    $window.location = dest;
}
```

remember to put $window on your controller function.